# logstash log parsing with regex and grok

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

Hello I have below logs

```
12-Apr-2021 16:11:41.078 WARNING [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user [uv19nb]
12-Apr-2021 16:01:01.505 FINE [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate Failed to authenticate user [uv19nb] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm]
12-Apr-2021 17:12:45.289 FINE [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.doAuthenticate Authentication of 'uv19nb' was successful
```

I am trying to build a pattern for these for logstash.

I have following

```
%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}\s%{WORD:severity}\s\[%{DATA:thread}\]\s%{NOTSPACE:type_log}
```

which parses below

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    "12-Apr-2021 16:01:01.505"
  ],
  "severity": [
    "FINE"
  ],
  "thread": [
    "https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-8"
  ],
  "type_log": [
    "org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate"
  ]
}
```

and i would like to parse  log as 2 parts as the bold ones and the user name  what would you advise please?

**An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user** [uv19nb]

**Failed to authenticate user** [uv19nb] with realm [org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm]

**Authentication of** 'uv19nb' was successful

I have tried using `(?<action>[^\[]*)` and `(?<action>[^']*)` but they only capture if the next character is either `[` or `'`.

I need some regex/grok pattern to catch all the sentence until any special character I believe and for user name I need to extract numbers and letters from `[]` and `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the `MY_DATE_PATTERN` works well for you, you can use

```
%{MY_DATE_PATTERN:timestamp}\s+%{WORD:severity}\s+\[%{DATA:thread}\]\s+%{NOTSPACE:type_log}\s+(?<action>\w(?:[\w\s]*\w)?)
```

I added `\s+(?<action>\w(?:[\w\s]*\w)?)`:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?<action>\w(?:[\w\s]*\w)?)` - Group "action":

  - `\w` - a word char followed with
  - `(?:[\w\s]*\w)?` - an optional occurrence of zero or more word and whitespace chars and then an obligatory word char.

Comment: perfect this seems to be working!! thank you !  would you have any idea how to parse the userid which is either inside of the '' or []

Comment: @HzlAysen Append `(?:\s+['\[](?<user>[^\]']+))?` at the end of the pattern.